# android - Installed app section shows package name instead of app name for my own application

Tags: android, android-manifest

[Screen shot of installed app section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrA6U.png) I created an small puzzle app. I created the android:label as Math. After installing the app in menu grid it shows as "Math", but in the installed apps section it shows the package name. Pls help me out.

[`Manifest code`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRY47.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tam.prasanth.MathFunDemo" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: What is the value of the String "@string/app_name" in Strings.xml ?

Comment: "Math Fun" is the value

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the application name (label) should be within the `application` tag and not the `activity`.

```
<application 
android:label="@string/app_name"
>
....
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot! :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Please specify `android:label="@string/app_name"` tag in application tag. And also set value of `app_name` in string.xml to your application name (Math).`

Comment: Thanq for the solution! :)