# PackageName.MainActivity displayed in android Permission - React Native

Tags: android, react-native, android-permissions

I am displaying a permission prompt on android for CameraRoll.
Here is what is displayed :

**com.packagename.MainActivity requires your permission to save pictures**

I have read that it is not longer possible to customise the permission title and message as so :

```
PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
  {
    'title': 'Cool Photo App Camera Permission',
    'message': 'Cool Photo App needs access to your camera ' +
               'so you can take awesome pictures.'
  }
```

Problem is, I don't want to display my packagename.MaintActivity, I want to display only my application name.
Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have your label set up? If not this is how you do it:

In your manifest file, set the following:

```
<application 
android:label="@string/your_app_name"
>
....
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34762192/9723698

Comment: Did the trick thank you! didn't know we could add a label in the applicatin tag as well